# Multiple differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

I have a small problem. I want to design a "multiple differential amplifier". With this, I mean a circuit that, given the inputs and outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhlTft.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, it has four inputs and four outputs; each output has the difference between the corresponding input and the next one.

All inputs are "ordered" as voltage, and the power supply of the circuit is greater than Vi1 (the greatest of the four).

The application is for a battery monitor. The battery is composed by four cells in series, and I have to have the voltages of each cell in order to sample and compare it.

The k factor can be fixed to 1 or to 0.5 if it is better for the calculations, but if there is the possibility to change it in order to better fit the next calculations it is better. In any case, I prefer having a k value not greater than 1.

At present the only solution that comes to my mind is to have four differential op amps (even the last one needs to have a differential one since the gain should be 1 or less). This leads to 4 op-amps and 16 resistors. Is there any circuit which uses less components?

Thank you

Comment: I think there are battery management chips specially for this sort of application.

Comment: Does it have to be analog? Why not digitize each input separately, and do the math in software?